# Three instances of AMD HD7560D are shown in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, amd-radeon

I have embedded graphics on an AMD A8 processor running on Windows 7 Pro Media Center, it shows up as HD7560D. When I use the AMD control for graphics in the hidden Windows 7 icons (in the tray) it shows 3 "instances" of the HD7560D – a click on these shows the same options but there are different grayed out choices for each instance.

Should I have three instances? I thought there would only be one.

I do have some issues driving HDMI TVs at the moment. In fact the AMD graphics driver sees only ONE display even though I have two (VGA and HDMI/TV).

Better question: how do I remove these extraneous instances of the driver?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the AMD catalyst control driver? Are you running The latest version of the driver?

Comment: Thanks Brad - yes I believe I have the latest driver. Could it be loaded "over" the old somehow? It doesn't show any flags (!) in the windows hardware control areas.
Phil

Comment: @user205015 In order to regain control over your old account please see here: http://superuser.com/help/user-merge